# Loading Particular Div in Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on a PHP Online Test Project.

I have two files `Initialsetup.php` and `MainQuiz.php`

`Initialsetup.php`   : This file connects with database and copies the question from database and convert it into a array of questions, correct answers.

`MainQuiz.php`       : This file displays every question seperately. On clicking Submit Button it loads the next qusetion.

Since I included `Initialsetup.php` in `MainQuiz.php`, On clicking Submit Button it loads Initialsetup.php everytime. It has to be **loaded only once**.
   I tried `require_once()` and `include_once()` and everything doesn't fetch desired result.

```
MainQuiz.php

<?php
require_once('dbConn.php');
require_once('initialSetup.php');
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='login' method="post" action="">
   <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
   <?php
       echo "<h4> $questions[$easyCount]</h4>"."<ol>";//display the question
   ?>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Submit Quiz" />
   </div>
</form>


 InitialSetup.php

<?php
//Connect to Db and fetch questions
require_once('dbConn.php');

//Create a query to fetch all the questions
$query = "select * from easy order by rand() limit 5";
//Run the query
$query_result = $dbc->query($query);


?>
```

I am looking forward for a solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Check if the questions have been loaded and if they have don't load them again? Using something simple as `if(isset($questions)){` could do it.

Comment: we are not here to solve your assignments..   How to ask:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @VickyGonsalves I am not doing assignment sir...  I tried a lot & googled a lot for more than 2 weeks ... I am a newbie to php

Comment: We are not **clairvoyant** and we are not **looking over your shoulder** If you do not show us the code in question, or some sample code that demonstrates the problem, how are we possibly going to do anything other than **make guesses** Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Using requireonce loads InitialSetup file everytime @Epodax

Comment: And I never said / recommended using `require_once` (FYI, That is not how `requice_once` works at all.) There are too many things missing / wrong with your question, follow the link in RiggsFolly's comment.

Comment: I might be blind or stupid, but where are you executing the query?

Comment: sry Epodax.. Just added query execution..